# Data Table input type as text instead of search

Tags: cakephp, datatables

Data Table input type as text instead of search

I have a system that populate data table using CakePHP and the amazing part is

its search field was something like this

```
<input type="text" aria-controls="c_table">
```

And the date table i populate was

```
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="c_table">
```

How do I change my own populated data table search bar as input type "text" instead of "search"

```
var dt = $('#clients_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
"oLanguage": {
"sSearch": "Search"},
"sDom": '<"top"f>irt<"bottom"lp><"clear">'
```

Above is part of my data table declaration but I think that does not affect the search bar to be search instead of text, I wonder how cake PHP actually change the search as text for data table.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question, as it it a bit difficult to get to the core of your question. I understand you want to change the `type` of the search field generated by the DataTable library (by the way PHP is not at all involved in this process). I'd be very surprised if the library provided such a feature. You will probably need to customize the library.

Comment: There is no practical difference in `search` vs `text` (at the moment, and `search` is in fact only supported by chrome and safari) - if you really need to change, simply change the `type` attribute in javascript or jQuery.

Comment: @RandomSeed I want to change search to text type because of the look  & feel of the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, now I see where you are heading. You want to get rid of the ugly **×** when `type=search` on `<input>`'s  in Chrome and Safari? Simply :

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}
```

dataTables demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lwwv5jLe/**